# dynamically load fonts html jquery

Tags: jquery, html, fonts

I am working on a site that allows the user to enter some text and drag it into position, etc. I have gotten to a point I would like to offer a choice of fonts. Can I dynamically load fonts instead of all at once? For instance, the user enters their text and chooses to use "Generic Font 1" is it possible to load that font with jquery? That way I can offer a bunch of fonts without loading them all when the page loads. Also I was hoping to use google web fonts, but not a must. Just for clarity, I am currently using a couple of custom fonts and they load just fine.

Once again, Thank you...
Todd

Comment: How are you loading fonts now? Can you include a code sample?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a function I wrote recently for adding Google web fonts dynamically...

```
function addGoogleFont(FontName) {
    $("head").append("<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=" + FontName + "' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
}

addGoogleFont("Junge"); // for example
```

After that you just apply the font via `font-family` as you normally would.

Comment: Of course that's how you do it. Never thought of appending to the head. Thanks. I thought this was going to be unanswerable...turns out it was dead simple. Have a fantastic day.

Comment: @jedierikb Nice find.  It's doing pretty much the same thing as above, but I for one always like a bit of code from Google :)

Comment: In 2017 and using the solution @jedierikb provided.